# Flutter how to add select option

Tags: flutter

Flutter how can I add a select option I my widget. I need to add something like Radiobutton in this so i can select only one.

My code

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, bottom: 12),
            child: Text(
                'Checkout',
                style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'UbuntuBold')),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: Height * 0.06,
                width: Width * 0.9,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // color: Color(0xff04385f),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(12)),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(height: Height * 0.022,child: Image.asset('images/cod.png')),
                      SizedBox(width: Width * 0.03,),
                      Text('Cash on delivery', style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xff04385f), fontFamily: 'UbuntuMedium'),)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: Height * 0.06,
                width: Width * 0.9,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // color: Color(0xff04385f),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(12)),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(height: Height * 0.022,child: Image.asset('images/cod.png')),
                      SizedBox(width: Width * 0.03,),
                      Text('Cash on delivery', style: TextStyle( color: Color(0xff04385f), fontFamily: 'UbuntuMedium'),)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )

        ],
      ),
```

Its looks like this right now

[image]

I need to add select option like this

[image]

As you can see in image i need to add this slct option so i can select only one option

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can make a widget that you passes the text and the icon to create the "cards" you have (just for have less lines of code)

You will have to add to row a check icon such as the one you show in the second picture. Then I recommend you to wrap the containers with a GestureDetector() and use the property onPressed() and setState() to make a logic that changes the icon and the border every time you press on one of the containers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable which holds the index of the current selected option, and use the `setState((){})` method of the `StatefulWidget` to update the  `currentSelectedIndex` of the options list.

Here is a working snippet: https://dartpad.dev/5e1f5df75ab12ff3377f026fffc55df1

Code here:

**`main.dart :`**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final List<PickerItem> paymentModes = [
    PickerItem("Cash On Delivery", ""),
    PickerItem("Visa Card", ""),
  ];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: PickerWidget(pickerItems: paymentModes),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**`PickerWidget:`**
You can use this PickerWidget to create any type of option selector.

```
class PickerItem {
  String label;
  String icon;

  PickerItem(this.label, this.icon);
}

class PickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<PickerItem> pickerItems;

  const PickerWidget({
    Key key,
    this.pickerItems,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PickerWidgetState createState() => _PickerWidgetState();
}

class _PickerWidgetState extends State<PickerWidget> {

  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        PickerItem pickerItem = widget.pickerItems[index];
        bool isItemSelected = index == selectedIndex;
        return InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            selectedIndex = index;
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16.0, vertical: 4),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // color: Color(0xff04385f),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 24,
                    child: Image.asset('images/cod.png'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 4),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      pickerItem.label,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff04385f),
                        fontFamily: 'UbuntuMedium',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  isItemSelected
                      ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, size: 16, color: Colors.green,)
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: widget.pickerItems.length,
    );
  }
}
```